# Differential equation system with both derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I rewrite those two differential equations into a matrix and solve them?
$$c_1y_1'+r_1y_1=cos(vt)-my_2'$$

$$c_2y_2'+r_2y_2=-my_1'$$

$c=(c_1,c_2),r=(r_1,r_2),m\quad$ are constants.

What really confuses me, is that I have on both lines the derivative of $y_1$ and $y_2$ and not a typical system of the form $$Y'=aY$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering $$c_1y_1'+r_1y_1=cos(vt)-my_2'\tag 1$$ $$c_2y_2'+r_2y_2=-my_1'\tag 2$$ extract $y'_1$ from $(2)$. Now differentiate it to get  $y''_1$.

Now, differentiate $(1)$ and replace  $y'_1$ and $y''_1$ by what you obtained. You should get a second order equation with only $y_2$ and its derivatives.

After obtaining the solution for $y_2$, go back to $(2)$ to get $y'_1$ and then $y_1$.

Answer (score 1):

First rewrite the system as
$$c_1y_1^{\prime}+my_2^{\prime}=-r_1y_1+\cos vt$$

This can then be rewritten in matrix form
$$\begin{bmatrix}c_1&m\\m&c_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1^{\prime}\\y_2^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-r_1&0\\0&-r_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\cos vt\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Or
$$M\begin{bmatrix}y_1^{\prime}\\y_2^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}=-K\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\cos vt\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
At this point, if $\det M=0$ this will lead to an algebraic relation between $y_1$ and $y_2$, so solve for one of them in terms of the other and insert into the remaining differential equation. Otherwise multiplication by on the left by $M^{-1}$ results in
$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1^{\prime}\\y_2^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}=-M^{-1}K\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}+M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\cos vt\\0\end{bmatrix}$$